# Nevron Chart X Axis

Tags: c#, charts, nevron

I have some charts and want if user zoom into a chart, other charts show the same range on X-axis and left lines of charts fit in a common vertical line(as shown in the picture)

how to that in Nevron charts?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code shows how to synchronize the ranges of the x axes as well as how to align the charts left panels:

1. Synchronize the axis range:

   ```
       // make axes master slave
       chart1.Axis(StandardAxis.PrimaryX).Slaves.Add(chart2.Axis(StandardAxis.PrimaryX));
       chart2.Axis(StandardAxis.PrimaryX).Slaves.Add(chart1.Axis(StandardAxis.PrimaryX));
   ```
2. Align the charts:

   ```
       // align the charts
       NSideGuideline guideline = new NSideGuideline(PanelSide.Left);
       guideline.Targets.Add(chart1);
       guideline.Targets.Add(chart2);
       nChartControl1.Document.RootPanel.Guidelines.Add(guideline);
   ```